# Sed: how to comment out string in docker-compose.yml in

Tags: regex, sed, docker-compose

If I have the following lines in a file:

```
### PostgreSQL ###########################################
    postgres:
      build: ./postgres
      volumes:
        - ${DATA_PATH_HOST}/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        - ${POSTGRES_ENTRYPOINT_INITDB}:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
        ports:
        - "${POSTGRES_PORT}:5432"

### Redis ################################################
    redis:
      build: ./redis
      volumes:
        - ${DATA_PATH_HOST}/redis:/data
        ports:
        - "${REDIS_PORT}:6379"
```

I want to comment out the ports section for redis

The result would be:

```
### PostgreSQL ###########################################
    postgres:
      build: ./postgres
      volumes:
        - ${DATA_PATH_HOST}/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        - ${POSTGRES_ENTRYPOINT_INITDB}:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
        ports:
        - "${POSTGRES_PORT}:5432"

### Redis ################################################
    redis:
      build: ./redis
      volumes:
        - ${DATA_PATH_HOST}/redis:/data
#       ports:
#        - "${REDIS_PORT}:6379"
```

This regex works fine:

`redis:\n.{0,200}([\s]ports:)`

https://regex101.com/r/PBrUY7/4

But i cant do replace via sed

Answer (score 0):

`sed` may not be the best tool to do this,  try `awk`

```
awk '/redis:/ {f=1} f&&/ports/ {$0="#"$0} f&&/REDIS_PORT/ {$0="#"$0;f=0}1' file
### PostgreSQL ###########################################
    postgres:
      build: ./postgres
      volumes:
        - ${DATA_PATH_HOST}/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        - ${POSTGRES_ENTRYPOINT_INITDB}:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
        ports:
        - "${POSTGRES_PORT}:5432"

### Redis ################################################
    redis:
      build: ./redis
      volumes:
        - ${DATA_PATH_HOST}/redis:/data
#        ports:
#        - "${REDIS_PORT}:6379"
```

- if line contains `redis:`, set flag `f` to `1` (true)
- if `f` is true and line contains `ports` add `#`
- if `f` is true and line contains `REDIS_PORT` add `#` and set flag `f` to zero to prevent other `ports` to be comment out.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^\s*redis:/h;/^\s*ports:/{x;/./{z;x;:a;s/^\s\?/#/;n;/^\s*- /ba;x};x}' file
```

If a line beginning `redis:` is encountered, set a switch on in the hold space. If a line beginning `ports:` is encountered, check the hold space to see if the switch above is set on (not empty) and if so turn the switch off (empty the hold space) and then replace the first space on each line for all ports with a `#`.